# jQuery hide/remove DIV content after 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to automatically hide or remove DIV's content.
I have container where I put some messages.

```
<div id="msg-container"></div>
```

I'd like to show new message only for few seconds, it can be 5, 10 whatever, but then I want it empty, add new message, show it and than hide.
Of course I know the "trick" with setTimeout:

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $('#divID').remove();
}, 5000);
```

but in this option I have to pass this script with every message and it's not what I am looking for. I have also tried setInterval, but as the name says it's interval, so the message can be visible for 5 seconds or can be even invisible if it hits the end of the interval time.
Is there any way to write simple script that will clean my DIV exactly after 5 seconds after it was filled with content?

Comment: how do you pass the message? can you post that function as well?

Comment: Usually with ajax calls. Yes, I know that and I do it, but I'm looking for something better than adding JS script to the message every time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have a message container.

```
<div id="message-container">
</div>
```

Just create something like a message manager to handle this kind of feature.

```
var MessageManager = {
    show: function(content) {
        $('#message-container').html(content);
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#message-container').html('');
        }, 5000);
    }
};

MessageManager.show('<h1>Testing</h1>');
```

Every time you want to show something, just call MessageManager.show() with the content you want to show.

Comment: Simple, nice and easy :). Thx.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, your selector does not match the id of your div.

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $('#msg-container').remove();
}, 5000);
```

However, if that was intentional and you are trying to remove divs inside of "msg-container" let us say with class "divClass", it would be like this.

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $('#msg-container .divID').remove();
}, 5000);
```

Comment: I know, it was just an example. I want to clean #msg-container and it's not the problem, the problem is how to do it after it's visible for 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

One way to go is to use a combination of `setTimeout` and a custom event. Everytime you want to add a new message or set of messages, you will trigger this event and pass the corresponding message/messages to it.

E.g.

```
$('.message').trigger('message:add', 'I am your new message!');
```

and then

```
$('.message').on('message:add', function(event, message) {
    // do your thing
});
```

JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/6fk0ufz4/)

Or you can use a "growl" plugin, e.g. http://ksylvest.github.io/jquery-growl/

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(function(){
  $('#divID').hide();
}, 5000);
```

Comment: _from review_: While this may be correct answer, it will be great if you could add some explanation.